# Jquery Data table alphabetical filter

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery DataTable custom filteration

Here is my jQuery datatable. I need an alphbetical filter in my table. I use ajax method for filter data from database. But I have some issues.
When I filter the data the "showing results entries" in the jQuery datatable is not changed based on my filteration.
If any other idea to change filteration.

**table.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <script src="resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>SMART CAMPUS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center" id="header">
                Customer Details
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="well" id="well">
                                        <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="myForm">

                                <table class=" display nowrap table table-bordered " id="myTable">
                                    <thead id="th">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">Select</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Customer Name</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Storage Location</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Location</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Customer Address</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result}">
                                    <tr id="odd">
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkId" class ="checkId" id="checkId" value=${row.id }>${row.id }</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${row.name }</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${row.storage }</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${row.location }</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${row.address }</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                                <ul class="pagination" id="filterButton">
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('0')">All</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('A')">A</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('B')">B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('C')">C</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('D')">D</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('E')">E</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('F')">F</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('G')">G</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('H')">H</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('I')">I</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('J')">J</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('K')">K</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('L')">L</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('M')">M</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('N')">N</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('O')">O</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('P')">P</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('Q')">Q</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('R')">R</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('S')">S</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('T')">T</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('U')">U</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('V')">V</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('W')">W</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('X')">X</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('Y')">Y</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadEquipementModelStartwith('Z')">Z</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                                 </div>
                                <a  class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-5" href="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" id="edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</a>
                                <a  class=" btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_validate()" id="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete</a>
                        </form>
                        <!-- <button class="btn-primary" id="filterButton">Filter</button>-->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

        <script>

        //For DataTable
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myTable').DataTable( {
});

function callAjaxMethod(type,url,param,successMethod)
{
    try
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:type,
            data:param,
            success:function(result)
            {
                successMethod(result);
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err)
    }
}
//Loading data
/* This function used for sorting based on the letter */
function loadEquipementModelStartwith(letter)
{
    try
    {
        var param = {"startLetter":letter};
        callAjaxMethod("POST","sortEquipmentModel",param,startwithEquipmentModel);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
function startwithEquipmentModel(result)
{
    try
    {
        alert(result.length);

          var rowLength =  result.length;
        var content="";
        var id,name,storage,location,address;

        if(rowLength === 0)
        {
            content +=  "<tr><td colspan='4' class = 'star'><center><b> Data not found...</b></center></td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            for (var index = 0;index<rowLength;index++)
            {
                try
                {
                    id = result[index].id;
                    name = result[index].name;
                    storage = result[index].storage;
                    location = result[index].location;
                    address = result[index].address;

                    content += "<tr>";
                    content += "<td>"+(index+1)+". <input type='checkbox'  name='equTypeId' class ='checkList' value= '"+id+"'></td>";
                    content += "<td>"+name+"</td>";
                    content += "<td>"+storage+"</td>";
                    content += "<td>"+location+"</td>";
                    content += "<td>"+address+"</td>";
                    content += "</tr>";
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err.desc);
                }
            }
        }
        $('#myTable tbody').html(content);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.desc);
    }
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UsersDAO.java**

```
public List<Users> sortData(String letter)
{
    String sql= "";
    sql = "SELECT  id a, name b ,storage c ,location d ,address e from customer where name is not null";
    if(!"0".equals(letter))
        sql += " AND name LIKE '"+letter+"%'";
    System.out.println(sql);
    return jdbc.query(sql,new listRowMapper());
}

private static final class listRowMapper implements RowMapper<Users>
{
    public Users mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rowNum)throws SQLException
    {
        Users user=new Users();
        user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        user.setName(rs.getString(2));
        user.setStorage(rs.getString(3));
        user.setLocation(rs.getString(4));
        user.setAddress(rs.getString(5));
        return user;
    }
}
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sortEquipmentModel",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Users> sortData(@RequestParam Map<String,String> request,Model model)
{
    String startwith = request.get("startLetter");
    List<Users> users = userdao.sortData(startwith);

    Collections.sort(users,new Comparator<Users>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Users s1, Users s2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
            }
        });
    System.out.println(users.isEmpty());
    System.out.println(users.size());
    System.out.println(users);
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use ajax for this purpose . just use bootstrap table and [Data table](http://www.datatables.net/blog/2011-12-08) . it will automatically add a filter , pagination ,sorting
refer this [for full description](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)
html like

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="bordered-table zebra-striped dataTable no-footer" id="example" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info">
 //rows here 
</table>
```

jquery

```
if($('#example').length > 0)
    {
        landing_table = $('#example').DataTable
        ({
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
             "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "sDom": '<"datatable-header"fl>t<"datatable-footer"ip>',
            "oLanguage": 
            {
                    "sLengthMenu": "<span>Show entries:</span> _MENU_"
            },
           "stateSave": true,
           "stateDuration": 60 * 60 * 24,
           "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],

        });

    }
```

Comment: I need alphabetical filter for my datatable.when i click "A" the table data filter and shows data that starts with "A". At the time of filtering the showing entries changed based on the filteration.